# XAMPP error after update windows 10

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, xampp

Earlier, a month ago the windows (I'm using windows 10) told me to update. Unfortunately after I updated it, my XAMPP got error. When I open localhost, it load so long and look so messy. And when I open localhost/phpmyadmin, it always said ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. I think it's problem come from old my XAMPP server, so I try to update XAMPP by download lastest version XAMPP. But it doesn't work, so I think it come from XAMPP. I've tried to install another webserver like WAMPP or appserv. But it still doesn't work. So i think it's because windows update, then I recover my windows version and everything going well.

Unfortunately, windows still keep force me to update the version. And suddenly windows restart himself for update when I left my computer for a while. So right now, I'm facing the same case.

Is there any solution without recover the version of windows?

Thanks in advance. Sorry for my bad english.